# Valores default em um select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Galera, preciso saber eu faço pra chamar um select2 com múltiplos valores default.
Ou seja, como deixar opções pré-existentes no select2.

Exemplo:

Tenho uma lista da base de dados 'nome','nome2','nome3'. Quero que quando carregue a página, venha selecionado por padrão 'nome' e 'nome2'

Detalhe, não estou usando uma lista  mas um `<input type="text">`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta pergunta precisa de mais detalhe. Que código já experimentou? que erro está a dar? qual a tua estrutura de html actual?

Comment: Votei para reabrir, apesar da pergunta ainda está mal formulada, porque entendi o que o AP deseja e ainda preciso cita citar uma questão sobre a versão 4.0 do Select2 aonde muda um detalhe.

Answer (score 1):

Como está na própria documentação do [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array), você pode criar as opções dinamicamente através de um array:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

  $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
    data: data
  });

  $(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
    data: data
  });
</script>
```

```html
<select class="js-example-data-array"></select>

<select class="js-example-data-array-selected">
  <option value="2" selected="selected">duplicate</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Esta resposta deveria ser um comentário, para facilitar os utilizadores

Comment: atualizei a informação